# Sort array and create a JSON object for each element in the array

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

In my database, I have a column that stores an array of elements, g.e, {"B", "A", "C"}. And I am trying to firstly sort this array alphabetically and then create a JSON from each element in the sorted array and then return it like the following:

```
{TEXTS : [{"TEXT":"A","sortOrder":1}, {"TEXT":"B","sortOrder":2}, {"TEXT":"C","sortOrder":3}]}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: The part `{texts = ...}` isn't valid JSON. If that is the intended output, then please also show us the input this is based on.

Comment: You are right, I edited the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorythm is simple:

1. Decompose array to row set
2. Sort row set
3. Aggregate row set into JSON object

```
select json_build_object('TEXTS', json_agg(t.*))
from (
    select "TEXT", row_number() over (order by "TEXT") as "sortOrder"
    from unnest('{B,A,C}'::text[]) as "TEXT") as t;
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=55c9653267a86b53c3426c15fe769358)